# Приложение не крашится при установке apk на телефон, но крашится если скачать из GPlay

Tags: c#, android, unity3d

Приложение не крашится при установке apk на телефон, но крашится если скачать из GPlay

Залил приложение в Play Market, скачиваю, и на некоторой части телефонов оно крашится. Тот же самый apk, залитый вручную на телефон(не важно, adb установка или просто закинуть апк и установить его) - работает корректно.

Краш происходит в самом начале загрузки движка.Буквально появляется логотип и сразу краш.

Сам краш расшифровке не поддался, addr2line не работает с 64 битными приложениями, а крашится именно 64 битное апк.

```
10-19 19:53:26.343: W/StaticLayout(1498): maxLineHeight should not be -1.  maxLines:1 lineCount:1
10-19 19:53:26.345: W/ExpandableNotificationRow(1498): setActionsBackground,null == view,mPublicLayout
10-19 19:53:26.357: E/CRASH(2943): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2 (SEGV_ACCERR), fault addr 000000767b481ff0
10-19 19:53:26.358: E/CRASH(2943): Build type 'Release', Scripting Backend 'il2cpp', CPU 'arm64-v8a'
10-19 19:53:26.358: E/CRASH(2943): Build fingerprint: 'HONOR/LLD-L31/HWLLD-H:8.0.0/HONORLLD-L31/132(C10):user/release-keys'
10-19 19:53:26.358: E/CRASH(2943): pid: 2943, tid: 2972, name: UnityMain  >>> com.FreeBacon.Hau <<<
10-19 19:53:26.358: E/CRASH(2943):     sp   000000767b482020  pc   00000076773acf34  pstate 0000000020000000
10-19 19:53:26.358: E/CRASH(2943): backtrace:
10-19 19:53:26.360: W/ExpandableNotificationRow(1498): setActionsBackground,null == view,mPublicLayout
10-19 19:53:26.382: W/StaticLayout(1498): maxLineHeight should not be -1.  maxLines:1 lineCount:1
10-19 19:53:26.386: I/chatty(1498): uid=10027(u0_a27) com.android.systemui identical 5 lines
10-19 19:53:26.386: W/StaticLayout(1498): maxLineHeight should not be -1.  maxLines:1 lineCount:1
```

Если кто сталкивался с таким поведением, подскажите пожалуйста, в чем разница одного и того же апк скачанного с Play Market и установленного вручную, и посоветуйте способ расшифровки крашей с 64 битного апк. Заливал в стор и AppBundle и просто Apk, результат один, лог выше взят с apk

Comment: Попробуйте в apk формате заливать на Google Play, а не в Bundle

Comment: Да, изначально так и поступил. Но краш остался

Comment: попробуйте для начала посмотреть внимательно на код при инициализации приложения.

Comment: файл устанавливается на одно и то же устройство?

Comment: @ru38irk
Да, абсолютно. Собираем апк, заливаем на телефон - работает. Заливаем в маркет, скачиваем - кращ на старте

Comment: для логирования используйте mLogcat - он через ADB работает, просто немного покрасивше всё делает, т.е. потрошит логи нативными способами андройда. Чтобы найти логи от Unity - нажмите ПКМ на стену логов и там будет Refilter. Впишите слово Unity в поле тэг. Найдите ошибку - скиньте сюда, если сами не поймёте)

Comment: @M.Green
Ваш совет помог! Логи стали читаемее и проблема стала видна в vdso.lib Напишу подробнее в ответе

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В итоге @M.Green порекомендовал использовать некий улучшенный mLogCat, и действительно, логи стали читаемее! В краше стало фигурировать некое vdso, поиск по которым дал вот этот пост
https://forum.unity.com/threads/unity-2019-x-il2cpp-crash-on-android-8.673972/
Вкратце, гугл на андроид 8(возможно и на других версиях, но тут проблема подтверждена), хранит данные приложения после удаления. При повторной загрузке приложения из маркета, он пытается использовать что то от старой версии приложения, и часто они не совместимы. Чинится это отключением резервного копирования данных приложения в настройках самого андроида. Мне лично помогло. Также можно добавить в манифест

```
android: allowBackup = "false";
```